# Firebase forgot password domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

I have a firebase app offering the "forgot password" capability.

Is there a way to make it link to my own hosting domain instead of appName-id.firebaseapp.com?

I tried adding it from hosting, and for the email templates, but I can't find a way to do it for the reset password link

Answer (score 3):

It seems like I can change the action URL, to:

https://my-hosting-domain/__/auth/action

So I guess this is solved

Comment: what did you do i have my website domain name i want it in place of hosting domain name or if not possible link should open in app my app

Comment: in Hosting/domains you need to add your url/subdomain URL and then in the Authentication tab, click the pencil, click the customize action URL and add in your domain...just make sure it ends with '__/auth/action' ...i kept getting stuck without it